# RVM on debian and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debian, rvm

I'm following https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Installing-on-Debian and trying to get RVM installed on debian. Executing

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

gives me nothing, it does not result in anything. I have curl installed but the command doesn't generate any output.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download https://rvm.io/install/rvm via browser and then execute bash ./rvm . The command you entered actually executes the same.

EDIT: the new way:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io -o rvm-installer
chmod +x rvm-installer
./rvm-installer
rm -f rvm-installer
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

The former command was using `-s` without `-S` which was hiding errors from `curl`.

Comment: Using wget gives me "Connection refused". I need to download this to my server, opening a browser is not an option

Comment: Then just Download it yourself and scp it to your server or use ftp.